# Evitar que un usuario coloque una reservacion en el mismo dia y hora que otra (PHP)

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, validación

Tengo un problema con un query de sql, por alguna razon este query no quiere mostrar una advertencia cuando el usuario trata de reservar una clase en un salon a la misma hora y en el mismo dia.

No se si es que tiene demasiadas condiciones o tengo un error alli.

Aqui dejo el dump de la base de datos, quite los datos privados.
https://pastebin.com/22D648iS

El html y php

diseno.php

```
<div id="formularionuevaclase"> <!-- El formulario para hacer una nueva clase -->

<center><h2>Nueva clase</h2></center>
<center><h3>Todos los campos son requeridos</h3></center>
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://browser-update.org/es/update-browser.html" target="_blank">Si no puede ver los campos de fecha y hora, haga click para ver si necesita actualizar su navegador</a></div> 
<form method="POST" action ="diseno.php"/> <!-- El formulario en si -->
<?php include('errors.php'); ?>
<label for="nom"><b>Nombre del profesor:</b></label> 
<input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['nombre']); ?>" placeholder="Escriba el nombre del profesor" name="nombre" id ="nombre"<?php echo $nombre; ?> ></input>

<label for="mat"><b>Materia que da:</b></label>


<select name="materia" id="materia" <?php echo $materia; ?>> 
<option value="DISENO I">DISEÑO I</option>  
<option value="DISENO II">DISEÑO II</option>  
<option value="DISENO III">DISEÑO III</option> 
<option value="DISENO IV">DISEÑO IV</option> 
<option value="DISENO V">DISEÑO V</option> 
<option value="DISENO VI">DISEÑO VI</option> 
<option value="DISENO VII">DISEÑO VII</option> 
<option value="DISENO VIII">DISEÑO VIII</option> 
<option value="DISENO IX">DISEÑO IX</option> 
<option value="DISENO X">DISEÑO X</option>
<option value="DIBUJO TECNICO">DIBUJO TECNICO</option>  
<option value="COLOR">COLOR</option>  
<option value="CREATIVIDAD">CREATIVIDAD</option>  
<option value="DIBUJO LIBRE I">DIBUJO LIBRE I</option>  
<option value="DIBUJO LIBRE II">DIBUJO LIBRE II</option>
<option value="ILUSTRACION I">ILUSTRACION I</option>  
<option value="ILUSTRACION II">ILUSTRACION II</option> 
<option value="ILUSTRACION III">ILUSTRACION III</option> 
</select>   

<label for="fec"><b>Fecha:</b></label>
<input type="date" name="fecha" min= <?php echo date('Y-m-d');?> id ="fecha" required<?php echo $fecha; ?>"></input>

<label for="hor1"><b>Hora a la que empieza:</b></label>
<input type="time" min="08:30" max="16:00" name="fechaemp" id ="fechaemp" required<?php echo $fechaemp; ?>"></input>

<label for="hor2"><b>Hora a la que termina:</b></label>
<input type="time" min="09:30" max="17:00" name="fechater" id ="fechater" required<?php echo $fechater; ?>"></input>

<label for="num"><b>Número de computadores a usar (Máximo 5):</b></label>
<input type="number" placeholder="Escriba el numero de pcs a usar" min="1" max="5" name="numero" id ="numero"<?php echo $numero; ?>></input>

<div style="text-align: center">
<input type="submit" aling="center" id="submit" name="submit" value="Crear clase"></input>
</div>

<div style="text-align: center" class="container" aling="center" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
<button type="Reset" class="floated">Limpiar campos</button>
</div>

</form>
</div>
```

nuevodiseno.php

```
<?php
// Iniciar variables
$nombre = "";
$materia = "";
$fecha = "";
$fechaemp = '';
$fechater = '';
$numero = '';
$errors = array(); 
$res="EXITO!"; //Si todo sale bien

$today_start = strtotime('today');
$today_end = strtotime('tomorrow');

// conectar a la base de datos
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'prueba');

// registrar usuario

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// Obtener todos los datos de la forma
$nombre = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['nombre']);
$materia = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['materia']);
$fecha = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['fecha']);
$fechater = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['fechater']);
$fechaemp = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['fechaemp']);
$numero = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['numero']);
$salon = 'diseno';

// Muestra los errores si de alguna manera el usuario nego los required
if (empty($nombre)) { array_push($errors, "El nombre no esta"); }
if (empty($materia)) { array_push($errors, "La materia no esta"); }
if (empty($fecha)) { array_push($errors, "La fecha no esta"); }
if (empty($fechaemp)) { array_push($errors, "La hora de inicio no esta"); }  
if (empty($fechater)) { array_push($errors, "La hora de terminacion no esta"); }
if (empty($numero)) { array_push($errors, "No se especificó el numero de computadores"); }

// Evitar que el usuario meta la hora de comienzo igual de la hora de terminacion
if($fechaemp === $fechater){
  array_push($errors, "Las horas son iguales, cambielas");
 }

//Revisar si hay una clase en exactamente el mismo dia y la misma hora
$date_check_query = "SELECT * FROM reservatodo WHERE fecha='$fecha' AND fechaemp='$fechaemp' AND salon='$salon' LIMIT 1"; //El query en si que no quiere funcionar
$result = mysqli_query($db, $date_check_query);
$date = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($date) { // Si ya existe la clase, aqui esta la segunda parte del problema, no hace esto
  if ($date['fecha'] === $fecha AND $date['fechaemp'] === $fechaemp) {
    array_push($errors, "Ya hay una clase en ese dia y en esa misma hora");
  }
  }

//Si no hay errores, hace el insertar
if (count($errors) == 0) {
$query = "INSERT INTO reservatodo(nombre, materia, salon, fecha, fechaemp, fechater, numero, fechainscripcion) 
          VALUES('$nombre', '$materia', 'diseno', '$fecha', '$fechaemp', '$fechater', '$numero', now())";
 mysqli_query($db, $query);
 echo $res;
}

}
```

Lo que tengo en errors.php

```
<?php  if (count($errors) > 0) : ?>
<div class="error">
<?php foreach ($errors as $error) : ?>
  <p><?php echo $error ?></p>
<?php endforeach ?>
 </div>
<?php  endif ?>
```

Comment: Deberías poner una restricción `UNIQUE` a tu tabla en la base de datos si no lo has hecho, pues no deberías delegar esa responsabilidad a la lógica del programa. Otra cosa es que controles de todos modos que el registro no exista antes de insertarlo o lanzar algo del tipo `INSERT IGNORE` ... es es lo de menos, lo importante es que sea desde la BD donde se controlen los duplicados.

Comment: Intentare ambos metodos

Comment: No es posible debido a que todas las reservaciones deben estar en la misma tabla, y hay varios salones a los cuales se debe reservar. Lo que necesito hacer es evitar que haya una clase en exactamente el mismo dia y hora en el salon en si

Comment: Precisamente, entonces tienes que poner una restricción `UNIQUE` que abarque todas las columnas que no se pueden repetir. Las restricciones se pueden aplicar sobre una columna o sobre varias columnas. Por ejemplo, si pones una restricción `UNIQUE` sobre `fecha, salon`  evitará duplicados en la misma fecha y el mismo salón. ¿Me explico?

Comment: Lo intente y funciona pero no es lo que quiero. Lee la estructura de la base de datos que tengo para ver si me puedes entender, porque si pongo UNIQUE sobre fecha, evita que no se pueda reservar en otro salon EN LA MISMA FECHA, y no puedo colocar UNIQUE en salon porque cada registro tiene una clase en su su fila y los datos se deben repetir

Comment: Por eso lo que te dice @A.Cedano es que añadas el indice sobre ambos campos. Algo así: `ALTER TABLE `reservatodo` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `index2` (`salon` ASC, `fecha` ASC, `fechaemp` ASC);`

Comment: De todas formas, aparte de la restricción en la base de datos, debes verificar que las clases no se solapen parcialmente, por lo tanto debes verificar también la hora final.